# Rewriting public assets to omit file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, assets, clean-urls

For the sake of formality, I want to trim my asset URIs so that file extensions are omitted.

For example, if I request `/resources/stylesheets/common`, Apache will return `/resources/stylesheets/common.css`. At the moment, I'm using the following rewrite to get this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}.css -f
RewriteRule ^ /%{REQUEST_URI}.css [L]
```

This works, as it should. However, I need to also do this for other resources, like images and scripts. For simplicity, I would like to avoid repeating this approach for every type of resource.

**Question:** What method can I use to achieve this in one rule? I'm thinking something along these lines (though this will not work, and I can see why - perhaps Apache doesn't like guess-work):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}.(css|js|png) -f
RewriteRule ^ /%{REQUEST_URI}.%1 [L]
```

Comment: Mike, maybe this helps: `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable has  a leading slash, no need to add another one. This combination `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` holds the same system path the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable does. Finally, the *TestString* can contain variables and plain text only, can't include a regular expression, as you already know. To check if the file exists, I think several `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.ext -f [OR]` are needed. It works, but the (found) extension can't be passed to the rule. Therefore, several rules are required IMO, one for each file type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that looks like it's the tightest it can go. Pity... (And that looks more like an answer, that it does a comment...)

Comment: Surely the visitors to your site never notice the path for stylesheets or images, only your pages. Do you really need to hide the extension for non-page requests?

Comment: This isn't a public site, it's a private app.