# Grouping file extensions for re-writing URL's [.htaccess]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, file-extension

How can I group these two together; is it like ".(html|php)$" - please provide the code.

Note, the answer should work for all file extensions: what is your thoughts on removing every file extension; comment on the code used - as it is rare to find.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148830/rewriting-public-assets-to-omit-file-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

The *TestString* part of `RewriteCond` can only contain a plain string, and allows for server variables (`HTTP_REFERER`, for example) and back-references (`$1` and `%1`, for example).

As such, you cannot include an expression in the *TestString* - only the *CondPattern* (the second part of `RewriteCond`) allows for expressions.

The best that you can do is use an expression to strip out the extensions you don't want and then, for each extension you've stripped out, determine if it exists and rewrite accordingly - like so:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

# Step 1: Strip out extensions you don't want for files that actually exist

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.(html|php)\ HTTP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# Step 2: For each extension stripped, rewrite for existing files

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

*Side Note:* It would be really great if Apache implemented some sort of looping in `.htaccess` files - it would help simplify this methodology. Unfortunately, this is not the case, and so the above is pretty much the best method.

Comment: Thanks, it reduced the amount of code [in my htaccess]; reduced file size from 3099 to 2318; made the code cleaner. Although it is unfortunate that all file extensions can't be removed by a few lines of code.

Comment: You're welcome. And agreed. It really boils down to the fact that it's 'guess-work' that Apache can't do. This is why a looping structure would be great.

Comment: Although, I also wish to ask: how could I remove the word 'index' from the url, I have been using:'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]' - but this allows two versions: to work without it, and to work with it, hence, in the website I reference the one without and it works - but if the user types it in they get the word - the code above - that you provided removed the file extension even if you typed it in the address bar. Is there a way to 'wipe' it from the url, even if you type it in?

Comment: You need to do a redirect before a rewrite. Please ask a new question if you're having trouble.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684749/how-to-remove-the-word-index-in-the-url-htaccess

Comment: By the way, I read the information on the link you posted - very interesting. But I disagree with the: 'Surely the visitors to your site never notice the path for stylesheets or images, only your pages.' because surely 'good' users look at the code of the website, and actually if for example, you have a photography website with images of which are hyper-linked, it will show file extensions - and anyway, is it not a principle of programming: to be as clean as possible - with all code?

Comment: Looking back, I realise that I was actually wrong - there was no real point to it. Sure, it's clean, and perhaps that's what I felt was needed at the time. But now, it doesn't mean anything to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you pretty much answered your own question with

> is it like ".(html|php)$"

You just had to try it. See if this will work for you to group `html and php` files.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

There is one other possible solution. Is to not use the above code and use MultiViews. The one line of code below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

Comment: I thank you, but unfortunately it did not work for me: it removes the text as well; I'm not sure if there's some other code that is causing the issue here. However, is it worth noting that: 'RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]' is also used. Further note that it redirects to the index page because of error document.

Comment: Additionally, why wouldn't you want to remove all file extensions: it makes relative URL's cleaner; '@import 'typography.css''; OR '@import 'typography';'.

Comment: Additionally, I use: html|css|ico|js|png|jpg|woff2|woff as file extensions, I would REALLY appreciate if there was a short block of code [much like the second example you gave] to remove just the file extensions. Could you also explain: [(.+){2,}], why you didn't include the: [RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$], also [^([^/]+)/?$ $1.%1]. Note, currently, I have blocks of code for each file extension, however, this is messy and adds about 1KB onto the file - hence, I would love a solution for just the one block. // I thank you for your time.

Comment: made a correction to the last example. Also I took out this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$` because it's redundant and not needed because in the RewriteRule this `([^/]+)` says that there has to be value requested or it won't run the rule. So you don't need to check if it's empty with the condition. This takes care of that.

Comment: Tested new code - but it still does not work; does it work for you - do you think there is some code [in my .htaccess file] blocking it from working?

Comment: No I had not tested it, and never tried that, but Mike is right about the teststring. However you could try the other option I provided in my answer if you wanted to remove all extensions. Just be careful not to have folders and files with the same name. See my update.