# How to remove the word 'index' in the url [.htaccess]?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, file-extension

Currently, I am using the below code to remove the word 'index' in my urls - however, the issue is that it allows for two versions: one without and one with [the word] - hence, I have referenced the one without (in the HTML) - but the user still might type the one with the word.

How can I completely wipe the word 'index' from the index page:`http://example.com/index[.html]` goes to `http://example.com/index` but should really go to `http//:example.com`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(?:\.html)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me; have you also tested this on a sub-domain?

Comment: Try my updated answer. What is the full URL are you using to test?