# Why does .htacces hide extension not work?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to use .htacces for hiding the .php extension in address bar, I found the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess), but this does not work for me. My .htacces in root looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

If I click on a link, it shows *.com/stg/xy.php
I originally would like to show just *.com, but I read, that is not a good option because of visitors, so I would be satisfied with *.com/stg/xy/

FYI: I also have another .htacceses in subfolders because of pwd protection. Should I put the same code in all of them?

I also have *.pdf files to open, I want to hide the extension, or path here too.

Thanks,
D

Comment: I put them in subs, removed root htaccess, still not working :S And I also need pdf hide :)

Comment: Perhaps my answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30679350/1626250

Answer (score 0):

I think, I will use different folders with index.php and I will embed every single pdf file and use the method, mentioned above. I find this the best option in my case, because non of the "normal" methods work for me!